# Fast Web Designing (GUI)

Tags: php

I am back-end programmer like user of PHP.
Now I have been given task of designing front-end of a website.
What I meant by front-end is widgets like 'button' , 'menubar'.

So How can I do rapid development of these things.
Well we are using YUI3 framework for frontEnd programming.

I have learnt that we can use Photoshop for web designing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) a try, it can be very useful, and you can add many plugins to make it better (eg. Bootstrap select...)

**EDIT :** there is also [Topcoat](http://topcoat.io/), which is a very simple and clean CSS for building websites.

Comment: Both of these are free to use.